# Why power bi gives the following error :Fatal error encountered during data read.. '?

Tags: json, error-handling, powerbi-desktop

When I am trying to get my data from MySQL in Power bi, after some time power bi gives the following error: *Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'OLE DB or ODBC error: [DataSource.Error] MySQL: Fatal error encountered during data read.. '.*

Since I am working with json data type, I assume that perheps there is a problem with that, but how to solve this error?

I was looking for solution but I found only something about changing data type. So I did so but it stils gives me this error.

Answer (score 0):

The error there seems to be about the data source not the data type.
We ve had few of these before, it might have to do with some edit done in the data source which i assume in an SQL database.
One solution would be to revoke PBI access and grant it again.

Comment: Okey, thank you. I will check it out :)